# Python3 : " ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2.0' "

Tags: python-3.x

My code is the following :

```
def MonthID(month):
    """INPUT:
    'month' is the amount of months after the beginning of the computed rotation.

    OUTPUT:
    Returns the month ID composed by the 3 first letters of the month
    name and the amount of years after the beginning of the rotation.
    """

    year = str( (month//12)+1 )

    if month % 12 == 0:
        return "dec"+ str( int(year) - 1 )
    elif month % 12 == 1:
        return "jan"+year
    elif month % 12 == 2:
        return "feb"+year
```

...
etc...

Randomly, when `year` exceeds 1, I get this Error : `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2.0'`. Well... is 2.0 not a number ?...

I had no problem until now, the function worked properly for days... 
I tried to decompose my "december line" like follows, without a result:

```
year = int(year) - 1
return "dec"+ str( year )
```

Did anyone else got this kind of error ?
I guess the problem can come from the frame where the function is called but I can't figure it out... I just use this function with `print` to easily know where the code stands in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `month` is a `float`, `month//12` is also a `float`. This makes `month//12 + 1` a `float` as well; when you convert it into a string it becomes `'2.0'`. The interpreter is right to complain, because `'2.0'` is indeed an invalid *literal* for an integer number.

This means that somewhere in your code there's a call to `MonthID` with a floating-point argument, possibly having to do with how you load your data. Thus, a simple

```
year = str( int(month//12)+1 )
```

Should do the trick. Regardless, you should think about restructuring your code to make it more readable and less error-prone. Consider declaring month names as a tuple outside the function:

```
month_names = ('dec', 'jan', 'feb', 'mar', <other months here...>)
```

Then:

```
def MonthID(month):
    month = int(month)
    year = month//12 + 1
    if month % 12 == 0:
        year -= 1
    return month_names[month % 12] + str(year)
```

Or:

```
def MonthID(month):
    year = int(month-1)//12 + 1
    return month_names[int(month) % 12] + str(year)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... I fund a workaround. It seems to work for now :

```
year = (month//12)+1

if month % 12 == 0:
    year = year - 1
    return "dec" + str(year)
elif month % 12 == 1:
    return "jan"+ str(year)
elif month % 12 == 2:
    return "fev"+ str(year)
...
etc
...
```